# Authorized client-side JS API calls with Google's gapi library with an existing access token?

Tags: javascript, meteor, access-token, meteor-accounts, google-api-js-client

### Some background

I'm using Meteor as an application framework, and I use the `accounts-google` package to authenticate users. Using the accounts packages is very nice, because it handles all the dirty work of obtaining access tokens, refreshing them on expiry, etc. However, I wanted more profile information about the user than what gets populated in the `Meteor.user()` object.

With Facebook, I was able to easily load their client-side JS library and make graph api requests using `Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken` and following the documentation on the API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api

### My Problem

When referencing Google's JavaScript API, the documentation states that when making API calls, the request includes the access token automatically, **but only when using gapi to handle the authorization requests**.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#MakingtheAPIrequest

This is not helpful when relying on a 3rd party authorization package (or when your application handles Google's authentication away from the client side).

Is there any way to use an existing access token in requests using the `gapi.client` library methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I struggled over this for a long time, and I was able to find a similar question posted here:

[Google OAuth2 - Using externally generated Access Token - With JS Client Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168688/google-oauth2-using-externally-generated-access-token-with-js-client-library)

However, this person already knew what had to be done, just not how to make the appropriate call, so it was fairly lucky that I found it.

### Solution

In order to make `gapi` requests using an existing access token, you must call:

```
    gapi.auth.setToken({
        access_token: "token_string"
    });
```

before making a client request. In Meteor, you can use `Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken` in place of the `"token_string"` above.

Documentation on the method is here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsetToken