# Picker API - manually set access_token

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

I am trying to use the `Picker` API using [this guide](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/), and following the guide works fine.

However, my app uses Google sign-in itself to log in the user. Therefore, the  `auth` step in this guide is redundant, as I already have an `access_token` from when the user logged in (I obtain this by exchanging the `auth_code` on the server using the node js google api client lib). However, when I try to call the function `setOAuthToken(oauthToken)`, using this old value of access_token, it shows me this screen rather than the Picker, asking me to log in again.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a `scope` issue - 
i wasn't updating my `refresh_token`/`access_token` with the new scopes granted (permissions to use drive)
`setOAuthToken(access_token)` works just fine

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you solved your issue as I am facing exactly same problem

Comment: How you updated your token with the new scopes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's happening since you are using Google sign in (which passes the ID token generated) and Authentication API (from the guide you are using). You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24997236/5832311) to set it manually.

> ```
> gapi.auth.setToken({
>     access_token: "YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"
> });
> ```
>
> In fact this token object is the same as the one you get within the gapi.auth.authorize() callback. So if something doesn't works as expected, you can add more attributes from there to make it work.

Hope this helps.